# How to write Unit Test for manager running dao?

Tags: unit-testing, architecture, tdd

I'm having a simple test design problem, which I would like to solve once and for all.

I'm pretty used to regular Java design pattern where there is some `Manager interface` (or facade)  and a set of `DAO interfaces`. Concrete implementation of `ManagerImpl` is using concrete implementations of `DaoImpl`.

Right now I'm at the point of implementation, where I don't have a database connected to my project yet, so I guess this is a perfect time to write proper unit tests without DB :-)

I was able to mock some methods of my manager by using mockito, but since the Test Under Method (or so called System Under Test) is using DAO internally, I would have to mock the DAO as well. Unfortunately I cannot do that without setting concrete DAO implementation in my manager, like `myManager.setMyDao(mockedDao)`, but now I would have to pull out this `setMyDao` method into interface, which of course breaks encapsulation and makes my clean and perfect interfaces look like garbage.

**So the question is:** How to mock DAO in tests while preserving clean `Manager-Dao` architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unit test concrete implementations, i.e. `ManagerImplTest`, which will explicitly create `ManagerImpl` and therefore you have all `setMyDao` methods available for mocks. Your test will not know about `Manager interface`.

BTW, it is not always necessary to create interfaces for everything. In most cases only single implementation of managers and daos will exist. If there is no any other strong reason (e.g. Spring AOP proxies or dependency separations), I guess it's better don't create interfaces for everything in sake of simplicity.

Comment: +1: valid point on `Impl` testing, however advice to get rid of interface *might* be short lived when it turns out `Manager` is dependency for some other object that needs to be tested (although due to manager's *kind of* global nature, that might not be the case).

Comment: @jimmy_keen `Manager` could be always mocked then necessary to test another code. And if something else "turns out", it is not difficult to refactor. Modern IDEs have "extract interface" refactoring, which makes the change trivial.

Comment: I guess I can live with superflous `setMyDao()` method. I thought I was supposed to test against interfaces, not concrete implementations (Manager). I guess I was wrong, sometimes it's not possible.

Comment: Yes, as I understand unit tests should test particular code (i.e. implementation), interfaces don't have a code to test. And each implementation has it's own dependencies. Testing of interfaces it is more likely to be integration tests, in this case you may wish to use e.g. `spring-test` to make a test for a spring context with auto-wired dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of `set` methods altogether and inject factory. This way no extra method is exposed (in fact, no extra method even exists) and problem disappears. Then in test you configure factory mock to return DAO mocks and from that point on it's plain and simple.

Comment: It is not good to mix `Dependency injection` and `Service Locator` design patterns. It just makes all things more difficult.

Comment: @kan: service locator? Mixing anti-pattern with anything is probably bad idea; I'm talking about abstract factory which suits well in OP's scenario and doesn't complicate anything at all.

Comment: As I understand, the factory you are talking about would return DAOs taking it from container. In real app (I mean not unit tests) DAOs will be created and wired up by container. Otherwise, how will it be implemented? Don't forget that DAOs also have own dependencies. In other words it is SL actually implemented by the factory.